# parse webapi object to similar object

Tags: c#, json, parsing, object, unity-game-engine

I'm getting some data from my webapi using WWW in Unity, and now I want to parse the json to my object in my Unity C# script.

Here is my callback method:

```
private void answersCallback(WWW wwwData){
    JSONNode questionJSON = JSONNode.Parse (wwwData.text);
    QuestionThemeRequest q = new QuestionThemeRequest();
    q.QuestionTheme = questionJSON["QuestionTheme"];
    Debug.Log (q.QuestionTheme);
}
```

And here I parse just QuestionTheme from the json object to my specific property in questionthemerequest.

But what if the object I'm getting in wwwData looks the same as QuestionThemeRequest and I want to parse the whole object instead of just one property? How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a `QuestThemeRequest` object that contains all the values of the returned JSON, you would need to read all the values into that object.  Then either return that object or assign it some member attribute.

```
private void answersCallback(WWW wwwData){
    JSONNode questionJSON = JSONNode.Parse (wwwData.text);
    QuestionThemeRequest q = new QuestionThemeRequest();
    q.QuestionTheme = questionJSON["QuestionTheme"];

    //Assign all the other possible values to q
    Debug.Log (q.QuestionTheme);

    return q;
}
```

Comment: but in questionthemerequest i have a list. Should i loop through the list and assign each property? seems like a very strange way to do it. Got to be some way to just parse the whole object?

Comment: The raw JSON gets converted to two types of objects.  According to Json.org (http://json.org/):  
  
`A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed list, or associative array.
An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an array, vector, list, or sequence.`  
    
I don't believe there's a way to just convert the JSONNode to QuestThemeRequest.  I think you **do** have to loop over it.